# How to do semantic Bootstrap layouts for data "display" screens in CRUD applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, accessibility, usability, semantic-markup

I'm building a database-driven web application, heavy CRUD stuff, such as creating, editing, and displaying people's contact information and other related data.  Most information out there seems to be focused on how to design Bootstrap **forms** for inputting/editing data, but not much out there about proper read-only (i.e. data "display") layouts.

For example, I could do something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 form-control-static">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 form-control-static">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
</div>
```

... and so on (for all profile properties).  But this kind of a layout seems more typical/appropriate for create and edit screens with actual form controls.

I'm just wondering if there are good examples of applications (GitHub or elsewhere), of nice semantic layouts using consistent Bootstrap components, with standard-based, accessible HTML, that someone can point me to.

In addition to the simple First & Last Name scenario above, you can imagine a ton of other "person" related properties (address, email(s), phone(s), etc.).  Just looking for something established to follow.

Comment: you can't do semantic using bootstrap, its bloated markup with divisitus and classitus. or rather, if you want semantic markup, don't use bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the description list element, `dl`. Bootstrap has styles for these and it is designed for creating lists of information:

```
<dl>
  <dt>First Name<dt>
  <dd>Jiveman</dd>
  <dt>Last Name<dt>
  <dd>Jivemanerson</dd>
<dl>
```

Bootstrap styles will target the element, so you do not need to add classes. However, you can add `dl-horizontal` to the `dl` element if you'd like to display things horizontally.

These elements also have [default implicit ARIA tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance) for improved accessibly:

> - dl: `role=list`
> - dd: `role=definition`
> - dt: `role=listitem`

Comment: Be aware that some screen readers struggle with definition lists, though that is not reason to *avoid* them, just to be aware for support: http://webaim.org/discussion/mail_thread?thread=7089